# How to define a variable with multiple specific custom types ? (in Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, variables, types, definition

Hi guys as you may know sometimes, it would be so handy and clean if we could define a variable which can store multiple variable types. this operation
 is easily possible if we use "Any" instead of our type name.
for example :

```
var a : Any     // defines a variable with ability to store all types except a nil
var b : Any?    // defines a variable with ability to store all types including nil
var c : String  // a variable storing only and only a String value
var d : String? // a variable such as "c" , but also includes nil too
```

in the first two ones we can store all {Int , String , Float & etc.}. also in the third and fourth one we can store String values while we can't store others such as "Int" or "Float" .
but what if in some cases we would like to have a variable which can store custom Types ? for example i want a variable which can store an "Int" value , can store a "String" one, but can not store "Float"s ?

```
var e : only(String and Int)
// some code like above, or even below :
var f : Any but not Float
```

is there any idea ? is there any solution please ?

```
thanks dudes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to use `protocols`.

Something like:

```
protocol CustomType {
    // your definitions ...
}

extension String: CustomType {}
extension Int: CustomType {}

let customType1: CustomType = "string"
print(customType1)
let customType2: CustomType = 0
print(customType2)

// Error: Value of type 'Double' does not conform to specified type 'CustomType'
// let customType3: CustomType = 0.0
```

In this case, values of `CustomType` type will only accept `String` and `Int` types (because of the protocol conformance).

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to achieve this functionality. However, a closer, and in my opinion, a better way would be to use `Any` type and then use a `guard` or `if let` while casting the value to your desired type. An example of such can be seen below:

**Example**

```
let a: Any    //e.g. you only want to store Int and String in this variable
if let _ = a as? Int {
    //a is of type Int
} else if let _ = a as? String {
    //a is of type String
}
```

Comment: Yeah of course man , also an other solution is to force it to crash if it was set to an unwanted value . but still it is not the way we wanted . i still don't believe there is no way to do that in a language like swift!

Answer (score 0):

For most cases, when you want to store multiple types in a single variable or in a collection you would use an enum with associated values:

```
enum StringOrInt {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
}

var e: StringOrInt = .string("Hello World")
var f: StringOrInt = .int(42)
var g: [StringOrInt] = [e, f]
```